# config UI in background thread then assign back to mainthread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Hi I'm a new swift developer and I'm trying to find a way to load all of my textfields in the background thread then make it go back to the mainthread before a viewcontroller appear.

Because in my viewcontroller I have like almost 20 textfield that need to setup like its style, placeholders and etc.. So it takes quite a while for the viewcontroller to appear when I tapped on the button that handle segue to that vc.

I know that I can use this to do the setup textfields in the background

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        <#code#>
    }
```

however I dont know where to put this code. I tried to put it in the viewDidLoad but that doesnt seem to work.

---

**EDIT: ADD IN MY CODE**

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents.MaterialTextFields

class AddNewDataVC: UIViewController {

    //Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveNewDataBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sowInfoInputsStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var giltInfoInputsStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var matingInfoInputsStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var farrowInfoInputsStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var vaccinTable: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pigTypeTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var chipIDTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var breedTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var subBreedTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dadIDTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var momIDTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var penIDTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var parityTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var birthDateTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weanDateTextField: PickerTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var arrivalDateTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var herdEntryDateTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var startOffDutySowDateTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var semenFromBoarIDTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var technicianNameTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var matingDateTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var estimateBirthDateTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var realBirthDateTextField: PickerTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalNumberOfNewBornsTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalNumberOfDeadNewBornsTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var averageWeightOfNewBornsTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var accoucheurNameTextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newBornDeathReason1TextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newBornDeathReason2TextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newBornDeathReason3TextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newBornCullReason1TextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newBornCullReason2TextField: MDCTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newBornCullReason3TextField: MDCTextField!

    //Properties
    var pigTypeController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var genderController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var chipIDController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var breedController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var subBreedController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var dadIDController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var momIDController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var penIDController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var weightController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var parityController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var birthDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var weanDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?

    var arrivalDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var herdEntryDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var startOffDutySowDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var semenFromBoarIDController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var techicianNameController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var matingDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var estimateBirthDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var realBirthDateController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var totalNumberOfNewBornsController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var totalNumberOfDeadNewBornsController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var averageWeightOfNewBornsController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var accoucheurNameController: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var newBornDeathReason1Controller: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var newBornDeathReason2Controller: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var newBornDeathReason3Controller: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var newBornCullReason1Controller: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var newBornCullReason2Controller: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?
    var newBornCullReason3Controller: MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?

    var allTextFieldControllers = [MDCTextInputControllerUnderline]()
    var injectedVaccinArray = [[String : Any]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTextFields()

        registerKeyboardNotifications()
        addGestureRecognizer()

        vaccinTable.dataSource = self
        vaccinTable.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBAction func closeAddNewDataPopupBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveNewDataBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func addVaccinDataBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let getDestStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "AddNewData", bundle: nil)
        let popupVC = getDestStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addVaccinDataVC") as! AddVaccinInfoVC
        popupVC.popupDelegate = self
        self.present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension AddNewDataVC {
    func setupTextFields() {
        pigTypeController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: pigTypeTextField)
        pigTypeTextField.delegate = self
        pigTypeTextField.addData(data: PIG_TYPES_ENUM.allValues)
        pigTypeController?.placeholderText = "Loại lợn"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(pigTypeController!)

        genderController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: genderTextField)
        genderTextField.delegate = self
        genderTextField.addData(data: GENDERS)
        genderController?.placeholderText = "Giới tính"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(genderController!)

        chipIDController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: chipIDTextField)
        chipIDTextField.delegate = self
        chipIDController?.placeholderText = "Số chip"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(chipIDController!)

        breedController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: breedTextField)
        breedTextField.delegate = self
        breedController?.placeholderText = "Giống"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(breedController!)

        subBreedController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: subBreedTextField)
        subBreedTextField.delegate = self
        subBreedController?.placeholderText = "Giống phụ"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(subBreedController!)

        dadIDController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: dadIDTextField)
        dadIDTextField.delegate = self
        dadIDController?.placeholderText = "Số chip bố mẹ"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(dadIDController!)

        momIDController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: momIDTextField)
        momIDTextField.delegate = self
        momIDController?.placeholderText = "Số chip mẹ"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(momIDController!)

        penIDController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: penIDTextField)
        penIDTextField.delegate = self
        penIDController?.placeholderText = "Số chuồng"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(penIDController!)

        weightController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: weightTextField)
        weightTextField.delegate = self
        weightController?.placeholderText = "Số kg"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(weightController!)

        parityController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: parityTextField)
        parityTextField.delegate = self
        parityController?.placeholderText = "Số lứa"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(parityController!)

        birthDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: birthDateTextField)
        birthDateTextField.delegate = self
        birthDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày sinh"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(birthDateController!)

        weanDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: weanDateTextField)
        weanDateTextField.delegate = self
        weanDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày cai sữa"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(weanDateController!)

        arrivalDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: arrivalDateTextField)
        arrivalDateTextField.delegate = self
        arrivalDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày đến"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(arrivalDateController!)

        herdEntryDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: herdEntryDateTextField)
        herdEntryDateTextField.delegate = self
        herdEntryDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày nhập đàn"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(herdEntryDateController!)

        startOffDutySowDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: startOffDutySowDateTextField)
        startOffDutySowDateTextField.delegate = self
        startOffDutySowDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày nái nghỉ"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(startOffDutySowDateController!)

        semenFromBoarIDController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: semenFromBoarIDTextField)
        semenFromBoarIDTextField.delegate = self
        semenFromBoarIDController?.placeholderText = "Mã heo nọc"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(semenFromBoarIDController!)

        techicianNameController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: technicianNameTextField)
        technicianNameTextField.delegate = self
        techicianNameController?.placeholderText = "Người phối"
        technicianNameTextField.addData(data: TECHNICIAN_NAMES)
        allTextFieldControllers.append(techicianNameController!)

        matingDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: matingDateTextField)
        matingDateTextField.delegate = self
        matingDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày phối"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(matingDateController!)

        estimateBirthDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: estimateBirthDateTextField)
        estimateBirthDateTextField.delegate = self
        estimateBirthDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày đẻ dự kiến"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(estimateBirthDateController!)

        realBirthDateController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: realBirthDateTextField)
        realBirthDateTextField.delegate = self
        realBirthDateController?.placeholderText = "Ngày đẻ thực tế"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(realBirthDateController!)

        totalNumberOfNewBornsController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: totalNumberOfNewBornsTextField)
        totalNumberOfNewBornsTextField.delegate = self
        totalNumberOfNewBornsController?.placeholderText = "Tổng heo con sinh"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(totalNumberOfNewBornsController!)

        totalNumberOfDeadNewBornsController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: totalNumberOfDeadNewBornsTextField)
        totalNumberOfDeadNewBornsTextField.delegate = self
        totalNumberOfDeadNewBornsController?.placeholderText = "Tổng heo con chết"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(totalNumberOfDeadNewBornsController!)

        averageWeightOfNewBornsController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: averageWeightOfNewBornsTextField)
        averageWeightOfNewBornsTextField.delegate = self
        averageWeightOfNewBornsController?.placeholderText = "Kg trung bình"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(averageWeightOfNewBornsController!)

        accoucheurNameController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: accoucheurNameTextField)
        accoucheurNameTextField.delegate = self
        accoucheurNameController?.placeholderText = "Người đỡ đẻ"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(accoucheurNameController!)

        newBornDeathReason1Controller = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: newBornDeathReason1TextField)
        newBornDeathReason1TextField.delegate = self
        newBornDeathReason1Controller?.placeholderText = "Chết khô"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(newBornDeathReason1Controller!)

        newBornDeathReason2Controller = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: newBornDeathReason2TextField)
        newBornDeathReason2TextField.delegate = self
        newBornDeathReason2Controller?.placeholderText = "Chết lưu"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(newBornDeathReason2Controller!)

        newBornDeathReason3Controller = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: newBornDeathReason3TextField)
        newBornDeathReason3TextField.delegate = self
        newBornDeathReason3Controller?.placeholderText = "Chết tươi"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(newBornDeathReason3Controller!)

        newBornCullReason1Controller = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: newBornCullReason1TextField)
        newBornCullReason1TextField.delegate = self
        newBornCullReason1Controller?.placeholderText = "Loại nhỏ"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(newBornCullReason1Controller!)

        newBornCullReason2Controller = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: newBornCullReason2TextField)
        newBornCullReason2TextField.delegate = self
        newBornCullReason2Controller?.placeholderText = "Loại yếu"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(newBornCullReason2Controller!)

        newBornCullReason3Controller = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: newBornCullReason3TextField)
        newBornCullReason3TextField.delegate = self
        newBornCullReason3Controller?.placeholderText = "Loại nhỏ"
        allTextFieldControllers.append(newBornCullReason3Controller!)

        for controller in allTextFieldControllers {
            controller.activeColor = Theme.darkAccent
            controller.floatingPlaceholderActiveColor = Theme.darkAccent
        }
    }

    func addGestureRecognizer() {
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                   action: #selector(tapDidTouch(sender: )))
        self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func tapDidTouch(sender: Any) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notif:)),
            name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
            object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notif:)),
            name: .UIKeyboardWillShow,
            object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notif:)),
            name: .UIKeyboardWillHide,
            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notif: Notification) {
        guard let frame = notif.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else {
            return
        }
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0,
                                               left: 0.0,
                                               bottom: frame.height,
                                               right: 0.0)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notif: Notification) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets()
    }

    func toggleFarrowInfoInputsStackView(toggle: Bool) {
        if toggle {
            sowInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            sowInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func toggleGiltInputs(toggle: Bool) {
        if toggle {
            giltInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            giltInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func toggleOffDutySowInputs(toggle: Bool) {
        if toggle {
            startOffDutySowDateTextField.isHidden = false
        } else {
            startOffDutySowDateTextField.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func toggleMatingInputs(toggle: Bool) {
        if toggle {
            matingInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            matingInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func toggleFarrowInputs(toggle: Bool) {
        if toggle {
            farrowInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            farrowInfoInputsStackView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func toggleParityTextField(toggle: Bool) {
        if toggle {
            parityTextField.isHidden = false
        } else {
            parityTextField.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}

extension AddNewDataVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let textField = textField as? PickerTextField {
            let text = textField.text?.lowercased()
            if !textField.isDatePicker && textField == pigTypeTextField {
                if text!.contains("nái") || textField.text! == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.gilt.rawValue {
                    toggleFarrowInfoInputsStackView(toggle: true)
                    if textField.text! == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.gilt.rawValue {
                        toggleGiltInputs(toggle: true)
                        toggleOffDutySowInputs(toggle: false)
                        toggleMatingInputs(toggle: false)
                        toggleFarrowInputs(toggle: false)
                    } else if textField.text! == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.offDutySow.rawValue {
                        toggleGiltInputs(toggle: true)
                        toggleOffDutySowInputs(toggle: true)
                        toggleMatingInputs(toggle: false)
                        toggleFarrowInputs(toggle: false)
                    } else if textField.text! == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.matingSow.rawValue {
                        toggleGiltInputs(toggle: true)
                        toggleOffDutySowInputs(toggle: false)
                        toggleMatingInputs(toggle: true)
                        toggleFarrowInputs(toggle: false)
                    } else if textField.text! == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.farrow.rawValue {
                        toggleGiltInputs(toggle: true)
                        toggleOffDutySowInputs(toggle: false)
                        toggleMatingInputs(toggle: true)
                        toggleFarrowInputs(toggle: true)
                    }
                } else {
                    toggleFarrowInfoInputsStackView(toggle: false)
                    toggleGiltInputs(toggle: false)
                    toggleOffDutySowInputs(toggle: false)
                    toggleMatingInputs(toggle: false)
                    toggleFarrowInputs(toggle: false)
                    if textField.text! == PIG_TYPES_ENUM.boar.rawValue {
                        genderTextField.text = "Đực"
                        genderTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    } else {
                        genderTextField.text = ""
                        genderTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    }
                }
            } else if !textField.isDatePicker && textField == genderTextField {
                if textField.text == "Cái" {
                    toggleParityTextField(toggle: true)
                } else {
                    toggleParityTextField(toggle: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool  {
        if textField is PickerTextField {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}

extension AddNewDataVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return injectedVaccinArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = vaccinTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "injectedVaccinCell", for: indexPath) as? InjectedVaccinCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.configureCell(value: injectedVaccinArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

extension AddNewDataVC: PopupDelegates {
    func popupValueSelected(value: [String : Any]) {
        self.injectedVaccinArray.append(value)
        self.vaccinTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

There are alot of room for improvement I know but I'm just learned swift so sorry if my code make you itch haha. right now I'm just focusing on make it works and will try to clean it up later down the road.

Comment: Do you aware about rendering UI elements in the controller? just draw your UI in `viewDidLoad` simply

Comment: No you have to set up textfields in the main thread, and creating 20 instances of textfield shouldn't slow down the main thread so I think there's another problem. Show all your code on how you're creating and adding textfields in the view

Comment: @sj-r I updated my post with the code of the viewcontroller with alot of textfield that is having trouble loading

Comment: Can you also include `MDCTextInputControllerUnderline` initializer?

Comment: @sj-r it is a class of Material components which is from a pod you can check it out here https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios

it is a styler for the input

Comment: @sj-r Hi have you found a solution for my problem?